# SQL Group By: Split Group when column has special value

Tags: oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

```
SerialNr  Date        Processstep  Comment  
--------  ----------  -----------  ----------
    2300  01.01.2018  Step 01      Comment01  
    2300  02.01.2018  Step 02      Comment02  
    2300  03.01.2018  Step 03      Comment03  
    2300  04.01.2018  Finished     Comment04  
    2300  05.01.2018  Step 04      Comment05  
    2300  06.01.2018  Step 05      Comment06  
    2300  07.01.2018  Finished     Comment07  
    2302  01.01.2018  Step 01      Comment08  
    2302  02.01.2018  Step 02      Comment09  
    2302  03.01.2018  Step 03      Comment10  
    2302  04.01.2018  Finished     Comment11  
    2302  05.01.2018  Step 04      Comment12  
    2302  06.01.2018  Step 05      Comment13  
    2302  07.01.2018  Finished     Comment14
```

I now want to get a table with the following information:

```
SerialNr  Processstep                          Comment  
--------  -----------------------------------  -------------------------------------------
    2300  Step 01, Step 02, Step 03, Finished  Comment01, Comment02, Comment03, Comment 04  
    2300  Step 04, Step 05, Finished           Comment05, Comment06, Comment07  
    2302  Step 01, Step 02, Step 03, Finished  Comment08, Comment09, Comment10, Comment 11  
    2302  Step 04, Step 05, Finished           Comment12, Comment13, Comment14
```

So I want to Group the `SerialNr`, but then also want to split this Group at the point, where the Processstep `Finished` occurs.

Any simple way to do this? Until now, I only can group by `SerienNr`. I don´t know how to split the group at Processstep `Finished`:

```
SELECT 
SerienNr, 
listagg(Processstep, ' - ') within group (order by Date),
listagg(Comment, ' - ') within group (order by Date)
FROM table
GROUP BY SerienNr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a few identifiers: you surely don't have a table named `table` in your database. You can't have a column named `comment` (it's a reserved word) and you shouldn't have a column `date`. In the future, please show the actual names - it helps no one to give such illegal names for testing.

Also - your LISTAGG use `-` but you show the output with `,` - I have no idea how you are able to do that.

Anyway:

```
select   serialnr, listagg(processstep, ', ') within group (order by dt) as processstep,
                   listagg(comm, ', ')        within group (order by dt) as comm
from     (
           select serialnr, dt, processstep, comm,
                  count(case processstep when 'Finished' then 1 end)
                        over (partition by serialnr order by dt desc) as grp
           from   tbl
         )
group by serialnr, grp
order by serialnr, min(dt)  --  If needed
;
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Your solution works perfectly fine, thank you very much. I only want to figure out why it is working. I haven´t used the "over (partition by...)" functionality yet. Do you have any ressources, where I can learn more about it?

Comment: @Christoph - If you have the time to learn about analytic functions, you will see that you are able to do a lot of things you always wanted to do. It is probably best to start with the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174  and some examples https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions

Comment: Great, I will have a look. Yes, I already have some ideas how to improve already existing SQL Queries. I didn´t know how much actually was possible!

Answer (score 1):

you need to have another column which allows you to group according to you "finish" lines.

```
select SerialNr, Date, Processstep, Comment, sum(grp) over (partition by SerialNr order by date) as grp_id from (
select *, 
lag(case Processstep  when 'Finished' then 1 else 0 end) 
over (partition by SerialNr order by date) as grp
from table
)

SerialNr    Date        Processstep  Comment      grp_id
2300        01.01.2018  Step 01      Comment01    0
2300        02.01.2018  Step 02      Comment02    0
2300        03.01.2018  Step 03      Comment03    0
2300        04.01.2018  Finished     Comment04    0
2300        05.01.2018  Step 04      Comment05    1
2300        06.01.2018  Step 05      Comment06    1
2300        07.01.2018  Finished     Comment07    1
2302        01.01.2018  Step 01      Comment08    0
2302        02.01.2018  Step 02      Comment09    0
2302        03.01.2018  Step 03      Comment10    0
2302        04.01.2018  Finished     Comment11    0
2302        05.01.2018  Step 04      Comment12    1
2302        06.01.2018  Step 05      Comment13    1
2302        07.01.2018  Finished     Comment14    1
```

From this table, you can apply again the same query except that you group by SerienNr, grp_id

Comment: Thank you! I didn´t know about the "over" functions - I will have a closer look at it.